# Why doesn't this code work? I got an error: incomplete type or does not name a type

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Why don't forward declarations work? I didn't implement any pointers in the constructor so it should work. So why doesn't it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo;
/*if i use this 2 lines i got first error if not the second one. How do i solve this? */
class on;
class off;

class state{
protected:    
    foo *_context;
public:
    virtual void t_on() = 0;
    virtual void t_off() = 0;
    virtual void handle() = 0;
};

class foo{
    private:
        state *_current;
    public:
    void setState( state* st){
        _current = st;
    }
    void on(){
        _current->t_on();
    }
    void off(){
        _current->t_off();
    }

    void handle(){
        _current->handle();
    }
};
class off:public state{
      void t_on(){
        std::cout << "on\n";
    }
    void t_off(){
        std::cout << "cant is off\n";
    }
     void handle(){
        std::cout << "handle to on";
        _context->setState( new on );
    }
};
class on:public state{
    public:
    void t_on(){
        std::cout << "cant is on\n";
    }
    void t_off(){
        std::cout << "off\n";
    }
    void handle(){
        std::cout << "handle to off";
        _context->setState( new off );
    }
};


int main ()
{
    foo asd;
    asd.setState(new on);
    asd.on();
    asd.off();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to implement state pattern in c++ but I can't understand how these pointers work.

### with

```
class on; 
class off;
```

---

this is happening when i try to use forward declaration.

```
main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void off::handle()':
main.cpp:45:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class on'
    _context->setState( new on );
                            ^
main.cpp:6:8: note: forward declaration of 'class on'
  class on;
```

If I got this error for class on then why does class off work?

### without

and this when I'm now

```
main.cpp: In member function 'virtual void off::handle()':
main.cpp:53:28: error: 'on' does not name a type
    _context->setState( new on );
                            ^
```

Answer (score 2):

To create an instance of a class (like you do with `new on`) you need the *full* definition. But at that point in the source code you don't have the full definition of the class `on`, only the forward declaration.

The common solution is to split the class into the class definition, and the member function definitions.

Like e.g.

```
// Define the class
class off:public state{
public:
    void t_on();
    void t_off();
    void handle();
};

// Define the class and its member functions
class on:public state{
    public:
    void t_on(){
        std::cout << "cant is on\n";
    }
    void t_off(){
        std::cout << "off\n";
    }
    void handle(){
        std::cout << "handle to off";
        _context->setState( new off );  // Can use off because it's fully defined
    }
};

// Define the member function of the class off
inline void off::t_on(){
    std::cout << "on\n";
}

inline void off::t_off(){
    std::cout << "cant is off\n";
}

inline void off::handle(){
    std::cout << "handle to on";
    _context->setState( new on );  // Can use on because it's fully defined
}
```

With the above code, when the class `on` and its member functions are defined, the class `off` will be fully defined. Then later when defining the member functions of `off` then you will also have the full definition of the `on` class.

Comment: This solves the initial problem. However, there is another serious problem in the OP's code: it leaks memory quite badly. Every time there is a change of state, there is a new object being allocated on the heap, with the old object not being freed. It is worth pointing this serious issue out to the OP because it seems they're learning C++ (probably coming over from a language with garbage collection like Java or C#) and it would be better to set them straight while they're still in the learning stage.

Comment: Thx, actualy I knew about that, but i was trying to follow  this [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/zAqpX9L8/) tutorial and learning one pattern at time. And here comes the second question. What is better, using a singleton pattern for states or creating and destroying objects every time? I think first look way better but...